# Flutter - I cant get BLOB from db

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get an image I Imported to database using DB Browser for SQLite using this method: [Display Blob as Image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549801/display-blob-as-image-in-flutter). When I'm trying to grab my blob from database, my variable type becomes _Uint8ArrayView . (variable which is referred as blob in the link). Therefore I cannot use decode since it expects String.

Why can this happen? Is it an issue with DB browser?

```
    Uint8List  image;
    var blob;
    this.blob=map['image'];
    print(blob.runtimeType.toString());
    this.image = base64Decode(blob);
```

Here is the error code:

```
    flutter: _Uint8ArrayView //output of print
    [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 
    '_Uint8ArrayView' is not a subtype of type 'String'
    #0      new Workout.fromMap 
    (package:gymapp/model/workout.dart:41:31)
     #1      _MyWorkoutsState.loadWorkouts.<anonymous closure>
```

Comment: As the error says, you're trying to decode an `Uint8ArrayView` instead of a `String`.  What `map` gives to you is not a `String`, check the `map` data structure

Comment: Yes but shouldnt I supposed to get String when I take BLOB from db? I dont know what to do with this Uint8ArrayView

Comment: Try to cast it to string. Try this way `String stringBlob = new String.fromCharCodes(this.blob)'